# How to identify what process updated all Profile records

Tags: managed-package, profile, scheduled-apex, developer-console, developer

All of my Profiles in Production show they were lastModified by a particular User, but I checked with him. He definitely did not do this.

We have Managed Packages running. Could they have done this? How would I check? Is that even possible for a Managed Package?

We have triggers and other processes. At first look at our Scheduled Jobs, the run times do not match the time when the Profile records were lastModified.

Please advise on how to debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processes, Triggers, and other automations generally cannot modify a profile, as you need either a deployment or Setup edit to make this happen. This can happen a number of ways, including deploying a Change Set, installing a Package, creating new fields, objects, tabs, classes, Visualforce pages, etc. Presuming the user is an administrator, they could have been making a related change and indirectly modified the profiles as a result. Unless you have Event Logs, it would be hard to pinpoint what happened, but checking the Setup Audit Trail and cross-referencing it for an action performed by the user at the specified time may provide an answer.